# How cold do Curiosity's & Perseverance's appendages get at night with all those sensitive cameras and lasers?

Tags: rovers, curiosity, perseverance, thermal, thermal-control

[image: cropped from PIA19920: Curiosity Self-Portrait at 'Big Sky' Drilling Site]

cropped from [PIA19920: Curiosity Self-Portrait at 'Big Sky' Drilling Site](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA19920)

[MastCam-Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastcam-Z), [ChemCam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemistry_and_Camera_complex)/[SuperCam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperCam) and [MAHLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Hand_Lens_Imager) are optical systems and ChemCam includes a telescope and a pulsed laser, but the spectrometer is separated by a connecting optical fiber; presumably to keep it tucked away some place warm.

How cold do all these systems get out there at the ends of various rover appendages? Are they insulated and heated, or like most space probes have been for a half-century simply designed to withstand large temperature swings?

---

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/51149/12102):

> ...(Perseverance) simply cannot maintain a decent temperature except for the most essential of systems.

---

[image]

[image]

**above:** from [this answer to *Has ChemCam been used to characterize the martian atmosphere?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46575/12102) **below:** [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Drawing-of-the-Mars-Science_Laboratory.png)

[image: Drawing of theMars Science Laboratory]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Colder than you think.

The [full document for the Mars 2020 rover external Thermal Environment](https://ttu-ir.tdl.org/bitstream/handle/2346/74064/ICES_2018_53.pdf) gives excruciating detail.

Basically the computing core is kept to a cozy thermal range of -40C to +50C
The cameras and sensitive instruments have "survival heaters", keeping them to various appropriate temperatures, some as low as -85C to +50C
The mere mechanical appendages are allowed to cool to ambient, which could be as low as -128C

The TL;DR highlight is in this image from the document
[image]